# Parameter Tuning Tool in Gurobi using Julia

Tags: gurobi, julia

I need to solve a hard MIP model using Gurobi.
There is a tool to set the best parameters combination to solve this problem called "Parameter Tunning".
How can I find parameter tuning using Julia?

Comment: https://github.com/baggepinnen/Hyperopt.jl, https://julianonconvex.github.io/Nonconvex.jl/stable/algorithms/hyperopt/.

Comment: The official tool has a cli-based variant. You can just just it within your julia workflow, e.g. by forking processes. I would also stick to gurobis tool instead of wrapping anything which does not know gurobi.